# a view disappear in autolayout, ios

Tags: iphone, ios, autolayout

The goal is no matter what I am in portrait or lanscape mode, my image will be located 20  from the left edge of a super view and the viewHolder will also be located 20 from the bottom edge of a super view.

What I am doing is

ViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *verticalConsImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewHolder;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConsViewHolder;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *topConsViewHolder;
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view removeConstraint:self.verticalConsImage];
    [self.view removeConstraint:self.topConsViewHolder];
    [self.view removeConstraint:self.bottomConsViewHolder];

    //the position of the imageView left edge is equal of the superview’s left edge plus 20.
    self.verticalConsImage = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                      constraintWithItem:self.imageView
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                      toItem:self.view
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                      multiplier:1.0f
                                      constant:20.0f];
    // add it again to the view
    [self.view addConstraint:self.verticalConsImage];
    //the position of the viewHolder's bottom edge is equal of the superview’s bottom edge plus 20.    
    self.bottomConsViewHolder = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                      constraintWithItem:self.viewHolder
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                      toItem:self.view
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                      multiplier:1.0f
                                      constant:20.0f];
    // add it again to the view
    [self.view addConstraint:self.bottomConsViewHolder];
```

However, when I run the app, the viewHolder is not shown at all in either portrait or lanscape. Image is attached below
[image]

What I am missing here, please help if you have any ideas about this. Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing this in code? If you set up view holder with constraints to the bottom and left in IB, it will stay there on rotation. No need to do this in code. I don't know how this relates to your other question that I answered. If you want things to stay at a fixed distance, do it in IB, if you need them to move in some way, you should do it in code like I answered you before.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the constraint from that view highlighted in yellow to the top of the view in IB, and delete all the code, there's no need for it. If the system won't let you delete that constraint, it's because that view has no intrinsic size, so you need to give it a fixed height first, then delete the top constraint.

I think the reason your view disappeared, is because those 2 constraints were set up in IB on a 4" screen, and the simulator is using a 3.5" screen, so to maintain those constraints, the only thing that can change is the view's height, which probably got set to zero or below.